# Mysql выбрать данные из одной таблицы и количество записей из другой одним запросом

Tags: mysql

Привет всем. Мне нужно вывести из бд список городов, а рядом количество зарегистрированных пользователей из каждого города. это можно сделать одним запросом?
Такой запрос выводит города:

```
SELECT id, name FROM cities ORDER BY id
```

А этим запросом мы посчитаем количество пользователей в нужном городе:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE city_id=$id //$id - id текущего города
```

Пробовал объединить так, не получается:

```
SELECT cities.id, cities.name, COUNT(users.*) as count FROM cities
LEFT JOIN users ON cities.id=users.city_id
```

Так вообще возможно или я фигню написал, надо двумя запросами?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то оптимальный вариант так:  

    SELECT cities.id, cities.name, (
       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE city_id=cities.id
    )
    FROM cities ORDER BY id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), cid, cname FROM
    (SELECT c.id AS cid, c.name AS cname, u.id AS uid FROM cities c
    LEFT JOIN users u ON c.id=u.city_id) newtable
GROUP BY cid, cname
```